# Pandas running slow even with simple requests (e.g. .head())

Tags: python, pandas, memory

Lately, I have found that while working with Python Jupyter, it takes quite a while for pandas to process even basic requests - e.g. checking the heads or tails of a dataframe .head() and .tail(). I am talking about 20-30 second kind of wait.

Is this a memory problem? I thought memory problem occurred only during more complicated operations (e.g. loop, merges)

Any insight on the problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: just curious how large is your dataframe ? and in jupyter when you call head, are you only calling `df.head()` by itself in a single block or is there some more code that is executed ?

Comment: You know, checking your systems memory consumption would be one way you could answer that for yourself, and one we cannot do for you. Your Jupyter notebook kernel *may* be using up a bunch of memory, and your computer is thrashing, but we cannot say that without you reproducing the problem somehow.

Comment: Thanks, Juanpa, I am not too familiar with memory consumption, will look it up and try to figure it out.  Karan,  my df  memory usage: 20.9+ MB  - 35109 entries per 78 columns,  does not seem to be excessive for a intel Core i7 (my laptop). How can i check whether my Jupiter Kernel is consuming too much memory?